# hardware accelerated graphics in linux guest for nvidia graphics card

Tags: nvidia, virtualization

I have the following setup:

1. first gen Ryzen CPU
2. a single Nvidia 1080 TI graphics card (propietary driver 525.116.04, but I've tried a bunch of other versions as well)
3. ubuntu desktop 23.04 as host(default kernel)
4. fedora desktop 38 as guest (but also tried 36)
5. virt-manager as my VM management gui
6. weyland on host (but I've also tried X11)
7. not a 100% certain what is running on guest re weyland vs x11, but I haven't touched any settings related to this in the guest.

currently, this setup works fine and I can use the fedora guest, but the GUI in the guest is laggy enough that it puts just at the edge of usefulness.

what I want to do is to enable hardware accelerated graphics in the guest OS so that the desktop experience is more fluid (at least this is what I think I need to do?)

I tried following this guide: https://ryan.himmelwright.net/post/virtio-3d-vms/ which seems to be blog post that most guides on the net guide to (or at least suggest doing similar things) to enable 3D Acceleration. In short, enable OpenGL on Display Spice and enable 3D acceleration in virtio video.

Once I do that, I get the following errors when I try to start up the guest:

```
Error starting domain: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 72, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 108, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 57, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1402, in startup
    self._backend.create()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1362, in create
    raise libvirtError('virDomainCreate() failed') libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor
```

I've tried looking up the error message but I haven't found anything useful and it seems like this should be fairly straightforward and "just work", but for whatever reason, it doesn't work on my machine.

I've read that it could just be an nvidia silliness thing, but not enough references to this to make it the definitive issue.

NOTE: games using the GPU work fine on the machine in both OpenGL and Vulcun so at the very least I know that the GPU *can* do hardware accelaration on Linux :)

Any help on how i can debug this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: roger roger. sorry was adding more info in edits and stomped on yours. updated